# ubuntu-tweak problems preventing update on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Please bear with me, I have only been using Ubuntu for a month. I love it so far, but have run into a problem I can't seem to find a solution for. I've been trying to install Anaconda on my system but have been unable to update and the errors are pointing to the ubuntu-tweak tool and bionic release.

```
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I have tweak installed and have tried purging ubuntu-tweak, but it says it can't be located.

My question then is how can I either

A. Remove Tweak and update the system?

B. Update the system without removing Tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnome-tweak-tool should be in the sources already. According to [the launchpad site of ubuntu tweak tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak) it is no longer maintained. You should be fine by just removing the sources—an uninstall is not really neccessary but you may give gnome-tweak-tool a try.

### Removing the sources

#### manually

The source is either located in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as a separate file and you can just delete it or it is written directly into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and you have to remove the relevant lines—but this is very unlikely.

#### via `apt-add-repository`

The ppa can also be removed by using `apt-add-repository -r` in your case:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:tualatrix/next
```

#### via gui

Disable or remove PPAs from the "Software Sources" section in Ubuntu Settings.

---

### Insecure Sources

Full story seems to be that updating from sources without Release files cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default. Have a look into [this thread on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054252/the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-armagetronad-dev-ppa-ubuntu-bionic-rele) for more details.

### allowing insecure repositories

According to the man page of `apt-secure` you can allow insecure sources by either adding `[ insecure=yes ]` to the relating line in the sources list file or adding `Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories` in `apt.conf` or `apt.conf.d` respectively.